# Django - Is it possible in a intermediate table to use an inherited ForeignKey for the target model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

I'm using django 1.4 and I have the following models:

```
class Newsletter(EmailTemplate):
    receivers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='newsletters',
                                       db_index=True,
                                       through='NewsletterReceiver')

class EmailReceiver(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True)

class NewsletterReceiver(EmailReceiver):
    newsletter = models.ForeignKey(Newsletter, db_index=True)
```

When I create a `Newsletter` object in my view by doing something like this:

```
newsletter = form.save(commit=False)
newsletter.receivers.clear()
receivers = form.cleaned_data['receivers']
for receiver in receivers:
    newsletter_receiver = NewsletterReceiver(user=receiver, newsletter=newsletter)
    newsletter_receiver.save()

form.save_m2m()
newsletter.save()
```

I can see that all the both the `Newsletter` object ant the `NewsletterReceiver` object have been created. Using `ipython` if I query both the `user` and the `newsletter` from the newly created `NewsletterReceiver` everything is fine, but if I query the receivers from the `Newsletter` instance then django complains about something I do not understand:

```
In [2]: nr = NewsletterReceiver.objects.all()[0]

In [3]: nr.user
Out[3]: <User: 3>

In [4]: nr.newsletter
Out[4]: <Newsletter: Newsletter object>

In [5]: nr.newsletter.receivers
Out[5]: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager at 0x10ea26f90>

In [6]: nr.newsletter.receivers.all()
Out[6]: 
<repr(<django.db.models.query.QuerySet at 0x10ee860d0>) failed:
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column web_newsletterreceiver.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...N "web_newsletterreceiver" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "web_newsl...
                                                         ^
>
```

Is this because the `ForeignKey` to the target model is inherited? Is there a workaround for that or should I have to refactor the models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding:

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

to `EmailReceiver` model.

Answer (score 0):

`one2many` relationship will be possible possible if there will be `primary_key`. Like when you join 2 tables, you have to give primary_key in join order.

Please add one primary key in models.

When u try to retrive data with `all()` function, it will try to join on primary key.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? If the problem is in the definition of a `primary_key` why if I drop the `EmailReceiver` model and move the `user` field directly in the `NewsletterReceiver` model everything works as expected without defining any primary key?